# Jquery how to count checkboxes from different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

i have problem with counting checkboxes that are in different divs. It has to count if there is at least one checked checkbox checked in every div, and when there is, it makes a submit button active, else the submit button is inactive.

```
<div id="collapseOne">
  <span class="custom-checkbox addspace pull-left">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <span class="box"><span class="tick"></span></span>
</span>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo">
  <span class="custom-checkbox addspace pull-left">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <span class="box"><span class="tick"></span></span>
</span>
</div>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $a=$('#collapseOne input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').length;
    $b=$('#collapseTwo input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').length;

    if(($a && $b)>0 ){
        $("#button").addClass('active') 
    }
    else{
        $("#button").removeClass('active').addClass('disabled') 
    }

});
```

Comment: Have you tried any solutions?

Comment: **Typo?** `lenght` should be `length`

Comment: `($a && $b)>0`? Hmmmm. A typo again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `length` instead of `lenght`

```
$a=$('#collapseOne input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').length;
$b=$('#collapseTwo input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').length;
```

as well as using:

```
if($a > 0 && $b>0 ){
```

instead of:

```
if(($a && $b)>0 ){
```

---

Edit: You also need to wrap your code inside `change()` function to keep track when your input has been changed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        $a = $('#collapseOne input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').length;
        $b = $('#collapseTwo input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').length;

        if (($a && $b) > 0) {
            $("#button").addClass('active')
        } else {
            $("#button").removeClass('active').addClass('disabled')
        }
    }).change();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B78ht/)**

Comment: fixed the typos and the if sentence, still not working